# Quickest way to find the max frequency element in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array of ids like 127415157,31323794... (range not known). What is the quickest way to find the max frequency ID in PHP?

```
$array_ids = array()
```

Comment: @medopal: No but I googled it and it looks interesting..might try it sometime :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 3);
$r = array_count_values($a);
$k = array_search(max($r), $r);
echo "most frequent value is $k";
```

Comment: +1, since this is most likely faster than the original solution I proposed, given that searching for the max takes linear time as opposed to sorting which takes `n log n` time.

Comment: @stereo: Shouldn't we use array_keys instead of array_search?

Comment: but there can be multiple elements with the same frequency. anyway it was a trivial observation

Answer (score 7):

```
// Gives us an associative array of id=>count mappings,
$counts = array_count_values($array_ids);
// and sorts it from largest to smallest count
arsort($counts);

// Gets the first key after sorting, which is the id with the largest count
$max_freq_id = key($counts);
```

The suggestion of using `array_search()` combined with `max()` may be faster than this, however, since it doesn't need to completely sort the array, and thus will run in `O(n)` time instead of `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Right, forgot that PHP's sorts do so in-place. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing the issue of multiple elements with same frequency:

```
$values = array(1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6); 
$freq   = array_count_values($values);
arsort($freq);
$max = $val = key($freq); 
while(next($freq) && current($freq) == $freq[$max]){
    $val .= ','.key($freq);
}

echo " most frequent value is/are $val ";
```

this will ouput

> most frequent value is/are 5,3

also, it's a little faster than using array_search and max combo...

Answer (score -1):

Try
[max](https://www.php.net/max)

```
$max = max($array_ids);
```

Comment: I don't think this addresses the OP's question - they seem to be dealing with *frequencies*, and thus I'm guessing they want the item that occurs most often in the array.